# Android gradle product flavors with wearable apps

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, wear-os

I'm adding a wearable component to an existing app which uses product flavors in the gradle build to build multiple versions of the app.

I know the package names / application Id's need to match between the mobile and wearable builds, but do I just need to copy the

```
productFlavors
signingConfigs
buildTypes
```

from my main mobile app. I'm not quite sure if all of this is needed to get things working or not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The productFlavors no, unless you are going to do something specific for the wear app with a particular flavor.

The signingConfigs and buildTypes you should copy, the wear app definitely needs to be signed as well.  You may adapt the buildType for wear such is enable/disable minify it you want from the main app.

Here's a portion of my own mobile and wear build configs

**Mobile**

```
    android {
    compileSdkVersion 20
    buildToolsVersion "20.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "org.codechimp.qrwear"
        minSdkVersion 18
        targetSdkVersion 20
        versionCode 26
        versionName "1.20"
    }

    productFlavors {
        prod {
        }

        dev {
            versionName = android.defaultConfig.versionName + " dev"
        }
    }

    signingConfigs { release }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }
    }
```

**Wear**

```
   android {
    compileSdkVersion 20
    buildToolsVersion "20.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "org.codechimp.qrwear"
        minSdkVersion 20
        targetSdkVersion 20
        versionCode 26
        versionName "1.20"
    }

    signingConfigs { release }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }
    }
```

Comment: One more question on this, as my flavours have different application Id's would I then need the flavours in the wearable app so that they match up?

Comment: Since the wear app must have the same application ID as the mobile app I reckon you would have to duplicate the flavours at least for the naming.
I've not tried this myself, avoiding the whole application ID changing mess so far as it also has impact on content providers.

Comment: That's that's what I'd guessed.